# Where can I find java ImageIo sources?

Tags: java, image

I'm trying to debug an algorithm that's using Java ImageIO.

But,  I can't find the sources for it - they're not in JDK6.0 sources.

Any tips on where to download them?  Note: I'm aware there's a platform-specific version that uses DLLS, it's the pure-java platform-agnostic version I'm after.

Comment: javax.imageio.ImageIO is just fine in my JDK7 sources and I'm pretty sure that I looked that one up in JDK6 as well. Note that most of the interesting stuff in the package is done not in Java, so depending on what you're after you'll still have to look at the c sources.

Comment: You're not thinking of JAI are you?  It was the mention of natives that makes me ask.  So far as I know, there is only one (x-plat) version of `javax.imageio`.

Comment: Voo : aah, yes it was in the sources jar all along.  I'd directed Eclipse at the Jar, but it's in fact a self-extracting archive, and the sources are hidden inside it.  All is well now.  Well, all's not well - I'm still debugging my problem, but at least I can see the sources ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Voo pointed out - the sources are in the JDK Source archive, it's just that Eclipse doesn't parse them in their 'unextracted' form.